# GraphQl with angular and nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, graphql

Hi I have been looking around to find a tutorial for Angular + Nodejs
+ GraphQL without any luck. My question is is it possible to even use it
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will break into server and client side:

**Server**
https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/tutorial-building-a-graphql-server-cddaa023c035

**Client**
To use GraphQL in your Angular application you can use [apollo-angular](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular). I linked to documentation that describes in details all the things, starting from how to install it to then how to use it and what are the possibilities.

My teammates and I are working on a tutorial that will include most of GraphQL, for both server and client sides. It's not yet available but I'll link it in comments as it will be online.